# GetAnywhere function in R

Tags: r

How can I see the underlying code in R to the sum function:

I tried:

```
  getAnywhere('sum')
```

but only get back:

```
          function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
```

with now luck?

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide the link where it has been answered?

Comment: It has been automatically edited into your question.

Comment: @Joshua - running debug(sum)  returns nothing.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to. You're going to have to look at the C source code. Follow the instructions/links in the last 2 paragraphs of the accepted answer.